# Power Series representation of $\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Can anyone work out how to do this problem, because I'm getting an answer that close to the answer in the back of the book, but mine is off by a + 1.

What I do is, I first find a representation for $1/1-x$ ( which is the integral of $1/(1-x)^2$ )

and then derive to get back to the representation for $1/(1-x)^2$. From here I think you should be able to multiply by $1+x$ and eventually get the answer.

Any flaws in my logic?

Comment: No flaws in your logic, so there is likely a flaw in your execution.  Perhaps you can elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k x^{k-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1) x^k = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$

$$x \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k x^k = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

$$\therefore \frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (2 k+1) x^k$$

Comment: can you elaborate on what's going on in the 2nd line?

Comment: I made an edit in the 2nd line which should clarify.  I am shifting the index in the summation so I can compare like powers of $x$ in the next sum.

Comment: How come you can shift series(0 to inf) k*x^(k-1) to series(0 to inf) (k+1)*x^k without shifting the index in the second part?

Comment: This is because series(0 to inf) k*x^(k-1) is also series(1 to inf) k*x^(k-1), hence the shift is here but hidden.

Comment: Can someone explain the very last line of the proof?Everything seems ok until the last line came into the picture.

Comment: @learner: Just add the second and third lines together.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks a lot.Got it.