# Power series of $\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2}$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

This question is continuing from the previous question here:

[Power Series representation of $\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345538/power-series-representation-of-frac1x1-x2)

I am trying to calculate the power series representation of the equation:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}
$$

My workout is as follow:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}
$$

For $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$:
\begin{align}
 \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} &= \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1-x}\\
&= \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)x^n
\end{align}

For$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$:
$$
\begin{align}
x \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} &= x \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1) x^{n+1}
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, $$
\begin{align}\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2}
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1) x^{n+1} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(x^n + x^{n+1}),\end{align}
$$
where range of convergence is $x\in[-1,1)$. When $x=-1$, $(x^n + x^{n+1})$ becomes $0$, and $(\infty)(0) = 0$.

However, the model answer is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (2n+1) x^n$, where range of convergence is $x\in (-1,1)$.

I do not understand what is wrong with my calculation. Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: What is incomplete in your approach is that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(x^n + x^{n+1})$ is not the canonical form of a power series, which should rather be expressed as $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ for some suitable sequence $(a_n)$.

Comment: What should I do? In addition, term by term, the terms in my solution and the model answer are different.

Comment: Was my solution wrong? The first term in my solution is $1+x$ but the first term in the model answer is $1$.

Comment: Minor things: $
\dfrac{1+x}{(1-x)^2}
$ is not an equation, it is an expression or with a very loose interpretation, a funtion; You should also specify around what point you wish to find the power series.

Comment: The question is from a textbook and it does not specify the center of the convergence for the power series.

Comment: "the terms in my solution and the model answer are different" Once again, $x^n+x^{n+1}$ is not an elementary term of an entire series, so that at present, you have no solution. A solution is to write down the whole thing as $\sum\limits_na_nx^n$ for some $a_n$ independent of $x$, until then...

Comment: Can I transform my solution into the model answer?

Comment: @GitGud Sorry but the fact that the power series should be a series of powers $x^n$ can be omitted without hindering the comprehension, it seems.

Comment: Also, I do not get it. If my solution is not wrong (it is derived from standard operations), how can it be non-equivalent to the model answer? You may say that my answer is not in the optimal form, but how can it be wrong?

Comment: *It is wrong because it is not in the form $\sum\limits_na_nx^n$*. (Last try from me, you do not seem to read the comments trying to help you.)

Comment: @Joseph You're not making yourself clear, but I know what you mean.So let me first clarify your question and then answer it. As Did said, the solution has to be of the form $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(a_nx^n\right)$ for some sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$. But that doesn't necessarily mean that $f(x)\neq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(x^n + x^{n+1})$ (for appropriate values of $x$). And this is what you're inquiring about.

Comment: Why does it seems that $f(x)\neq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(x^n + x^{n+1})$? You conclude this by looking at the first term of the sum. In your answer that is $1+x$, in the given solution it is $1$, so it can't tbe the case that $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(x^n + x^{n+1})$, right? Wrong, because it can very well be that the "sums" (i.e. the series) are equal even though the first term isn't. The same way $1+2+3=2+1+3$ even though $1\neq 2$.

Comment: I see. So you are saying that my answer could be correct, even though it is not in the standard form.

Comment: for $x=-1$, what you are doing is addition of two oscillating series which turns out to be zero. It is exact same thing like addition of $-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+...$ and $1-1+1-1+1-1+1-...$ becomes zero.

Comment: @Joseph Not exactly. I'm saying that it is possible that $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)(x^n + x^{n+1})$ for all $x$ in a certain interval, but the solution asks for a power series and therefore your solution simply isn't right because what you provided isn't a power series. Is that clearer?

Comment: @Amey Yes, the two series are oscillating. That explains why at $x=-1$, the series does not converge. I am clear now. What you are saying is that 'the sum of two non-converging series is a converged series' is invalid.

Comment: @git-gud Yes, it is clear to me now. But can my answer be transformed into the model answer?

Comment: @Joseph Sort of. **Hint:** Note that $\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left( (n+1) x^{n+1}\right)=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\left( n x^{n}\right)$, for all $x\in ]-1,1[$.

Comment: Another related question: if $a(x) = b(x) + c(x) + d(x)$, and $b(x)$ diverge at $x = c$, does it mean that $a(x)$ must diverge at $x=c$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not end up with power series yet:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1) x^{n+1}  &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)x^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n x^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (2n+1) x^{n} + 1\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (2n+1) x^{n}\\
\end{align*}

From here you can derive correct radius of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* In order to find the power series expansion around $x=0$ you could also use the *[binomial series representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*

\begin{align*}
(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{n}x^n\qquad\qquad \alpha\in\mathbb{C}, |x|<1
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2}&=(1+x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-2}{n}(-x)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=(1+x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+1}{n}x^n\\
> &=(1+x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^{n+1}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+1)x^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+1)x^n
> \end{align*}

Comment:

- In (1) we use the identity
  $\binom{-n}{k}=\binom{n+k-1}{k}(-1)^k$
- In (2) we shift the index of the right sum by one